# C++ header file/implementation file isn't working

Tags: c++, include, header-files, implementation

I'm trying to use headers in C++. I have `calculation.h` and `calculation.cpp` files. I called `add` and `sub` function with the necessary arguments which are declared in `calculation.h` file and implemented in `calculation.cpp` file. I have included `calculation.h` file in `calculation.cpp` file. But whenever I'm trying to run my `main.cpp` file, It is throwing this error!

```
[C:\Users\MAHBIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPy83Oj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'

C:\\Users\\MAHBIN\~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccPy83Oj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `sub(int, int)'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU9Gp.png)

`main.cpp` file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"calculation.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x=5, y=20;
    cout<<add(x,y)<<endl;
    cout<<sub(x,y)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`calculation.h` file:

```
#pragma once

int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
```

`calculation.cpp` file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"calculation.h"

int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}

int sub(int x, int y){
    if(x<y){
        return y-x;
    }
    else return x-y;
}
```

But whenever I directly include `calculation.cpp` file in `main.cpp` file or `calculation.h` file, it works! But I want to use the `calculation.cpp` through including `calculation.h`.

If I explicitly run this command in terminal, it works! Otherwise, it doesn't!

`g++ -o main.exe main.cpp calculation.cpp`

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp calculation.cpp
```

*is* the correct way.

The compiler will not go ahead and compile other .cpp files without you specifying them.

You may be interested in using a tool like `CMake` if you plan on bigger projects.

Answer (score 0):

The first way (the one that doesn't work) just launches this command line:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

which compiles main.cpp but not calculation.cpp. Having  `#include "calculation.h"` in main.cpp does not automatically compile calculation.cpp.

The correct way *is* this:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp calculation.cpp
```

It compiles both main.cpp and calculation.cpp and links them together into the executable file main.exe.